# Replacing a text in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I'm a beginner to shell scripting, I'm attempting to remove some text from a file.

abcdefghijk:12

How do I replace the ":" with a whitespace( I have attempted "sed" but my methods do not seem to do anything)?
Afterwards is it correct to cut the first column using "cut"?

Currently only thing that works is calling the file

```
while read line
do
  name=$line
  echo"Lines read - $name"
done < $1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with sed using it's substitute command s

```
sed 's/:/ /g' file.txt
```

The `g` at the end means that it will replace all ':' with space on each line, not just the first one.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
does file.txt automatically take in the name of the file I give its argument to?

Comment: This is a bash oneliner, no script. Just replace file.txt with the name of your file. The result will come to stdout, from there you can redirect it to a new file if you like (not the same). Or add `-i` to make the changes to the file itself.